# jquery mobile + jquery ui and page transitions

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'd like a page transition effect like the "slide" transition on jqmobile, but with the option of dragging between one page and the other.

I have the transition I want using [this plug in](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/) the problem is that this plug in needs jqmobile and my project uses jquery ui extensively so dropping jq ui is not an option. Is there any way the two libreries can coexist? (or any other solution to have this kind of transition)

Here is the working code for my two pages.

page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.pagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/Libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/Libs/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/Libs/jquery.mobile.pagination.js'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        PAGE1
        <ul data-role="pagination">
            <li class="ui-pagination-prev"><a href="page0.htm">Prev</a></li>
            <li class="ui-pagination-next"><a href="page2.htm">Next</a></li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">

    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.pagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/Libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/Libs/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='Js/Libs/jquery.mobile.pagination.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <script type="text/javascript">

                        $('div').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
                            alert('This page was just hidden: ');
                        });

        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```